# Detect iOS language

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to detect the iOS language in iOS?

Comment: Would you like to expand on that?

Comment: Do you wish to know which version of iOS ? Is that what you want ?

Comment: I saved your life by making this a real question.

Comment: Some suggestions for new SO users: Rafael, read the FAQ (see the very top of the page) and explore other questions to see how they are written. Never fill a question with just a sentence, but ask a clear question with code you already have, or have tried. Have fun!

Answer (score 12):

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0]]; // us
```

This writes into a NSString the current country code so you can detect the current language.

Or use this to get the current language and the region:

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]; // en_US
```

Comment: Using NSUserDefaults seems to be the right way to catch the localized language.